# Compare cells and show icons

Tags: excel

I have an excel macro that compares every cell with the previous and show a greater, less or equal icon :

```
Sub Up()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Worksheets("Général").Range("D2:T20")
MFC c
Next c
End Sub

Private Sub MFC(ByVal Rng As Range)

With Rng
.FormatConditions.Delete
.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
With .FormatConditions(1)
    .SetFirstPriority
    .IconSet = ThisWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Arrows)
    With .IconCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
        .Value = "=" & Rng.Offset(, -1).Address
        .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
    End With
    With .IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
        .Value = "=" & Rng.Offset(, -1).Address
        .Operator = xlGreater
    End With
End With
End With
End Sub
```

**Actual display:**

[image]

I just need to reverse the greater and less icons (to track positions: position 1 is better than position 2)

**Wanted display:**

[image]

Comment: If you want to modify the icon criteria, why don't you modify the code that sets the icon criteria?

Comment: Not just change the icon, but change the comparison rule to set the up arrow if the number is less than the previous and vice versa.

Comment: I tried xlLess instead of xlGreater but it didn't work.

Comment: Same here - but check this out - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835585.aspx. But there has to be another way I reckon...

Answer (score 1):

Considering an idea to switch **xlGreaterEqual** to **xlLessEqual** and **xlGreater** to **xlLess** I noted this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835585.aspx) that says:

> For an icon set conditional formatting rule, this property can be set to only one of the following two constants: **xlGreater** or **xlGreaterEqual**.

This is re-inforced by the UI where these is a limitation on the options that can be selected for conditional formatting with icon set rules:

[image]

So perhaps the solution here is to just reverse the sign on the data and then 'cloak' that with number formatting and use the code you already posted.

So in this example:

[image]

- First range is per your example
- Second range is your example where each value is `*-1`
- Third range is the second range with a custom number format of `0;0;0` to make negative numbers appear positive.

Code is exactly the same as yours (my changes are to ranges on my sheets); it's the sign switching and number format that get your desired output:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Up()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range

    Set rngSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E3")

    For Each rngCell In rngSource
        MFC rngCell
    Next rngCell

    Set rngSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:E7")

    For Each rngCell In rngSource
        MFC rngCell
    Next rngCell

    Set rngSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10:E11")

    For Each rngCell In rngSource
        MFC rngCell
    Next rngCell

End Sub

Private Sub MFC(ByVal rng As Range)

    Dim lngThisNumber As Long
    Dim lngPreviousNumber As Long

    lngThisNumber = rng.Value
    lngPreviousNumber = rng.Offset(0, -1).Value

    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .IconSet = ThisWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Arrows)
            With .IconCriteria(2)
                .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                .Value = "=" & rng.Offset(, -1).Address
                .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
            End With
            With .IconCriteria(3)
                .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                .Value = "=" & rng.Offset(, -1).Address
                .Operator = xlGreater
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that I tried this for the `.Value` assignment:

```
.Value = "=" & rng.Offset(, -1).Address & "*-1"
```

So that the `*-1` would be done at run-time when the formatting was applied - however, this did not get the desired output at all.